# What is the best way to get all ui elements of a window?

Tags: winapi, user-interface, ui-automation

I want to get a list of all UI elements of a window, In a way I can recreate them on another PC? Currently I am focused on windows but a multi-platform answer will be greatly appreciated. Thanks! (What I mean below)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go.

Option 1:  If the window is a traditional one where the UI elements are child windows (rather than windowless controls), then you can use [`GetWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515.aspx) or [`EnumChildWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494.aspx) to iterate through the UI elements in a given window.  You then would have to examine attributes of those windows, like the window procedure, window styles, and window text, to build a list like you're suggesting.  You could probably make this work for all the standard controls.  The problem is making it general enough to handle everything.  Lots of applications have custom control types that your code wouldn't be prepared to recognize, or it might lay them out in ways that aren't obvious.  You also won't be able to deal with windows that use windowless controls.

Options 2:  You can use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684076.aspx) to walk the tree of UI controls. This is how accessibility technologies like screen readers interact with applications.

Comment: Can UI automation see windowless controls?

Comment: @Dvidunis Yes, UI Automation can see windowless controls (assuming the windowless framework implements UI Automation).  For example, XAML, WPF, and Trident (Internet Explorer) are all examples of windowless frameworks that implement UI Automation.

Comment: @Dvidunis Also, UI Automation works much better with custom windowed controls, like split buttons (and other, more advanced controls).

Comment: Can UI Automation work with Java, Python, Chrome applications? Can it detect controls of these applications?

Comment: @Prasad Honrao:  Chrome--yes, the mainstream browsers have all done the work on Windows to make the accessibility APIs work even though they use windowless controls.  For Java and Python apps, I don't know.  I suppose it depends on the UI framework.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianMcCarthy. Do you have any working example to access Chrome browser elements using UI Automation framework by any chance?

Comment: @PrasadHonrao:  Nope, sorry.

Comment: This script looks promising: https://github.com/yinkaisheng/Python-UIAutomation-for-Windows/blob/master/readme.md